# Using VLFeat from C

Tags: c, ubuntu, vlfeat

I am trying to use VLFeat in my C code on Ubuntu 16.04.3. Following the [official instructions](http://www.vlfeat.org/gcc.html), I created a test file:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <vlfeat/vl/svm.h>
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  VL_PRINT ("Hello world!") ;
  return 0;
}
```

From the command line, I can confirm that svm.h is in vlfeat/vl. I then try

```
gcc main.cpp
```

but get the error message

```
main.cpp:3:27: fatal error: vlfeat/vl/svm.h: No such file or directory
```

Any advice on how to correctly use VLFeat in C code? Thanks.

Comment: Need `-I<directory>`? What directory is `vlfeat` in?

Comment: You're building the executable differently than instructed: `$ g++ main.cpp -o vlfeat-test -IVLROOT -LVLROOT/bin/a64/ -lvl`

Comment: @FiddlingBits Indeed but I still get the same error code with `g++ main.cpp -o vlfeat-test -I/vlfeatdir -L/vlfeatdir/bin/a64/ -lvl`

Comment: What directory are you in when you run `gcc main.cpp`?

Comment: @jwdonahue a directory I named `vlfeatdir` which contains `main.cpp` and the `vlfeat` directory (which itself contains `vl` and everything else for vlfeat)

Comment: Some compilers only search along the includes path when you use angle brackets `#include <d/f.h>`, but quoted includes are always rooted in the current directory at build time. Try `#include "vlfeat/vl/svm.h"`.

Comment: It's also common to see `.;` in the includes path or a compiler configuration that effectively makes angle bracketed and quoted includes the same. I normally disable these anti-patterns in my build automation. Better to maintain a clear separation between project, user and system level configurations.

Comment: @jwdonahue I changed to quotes and now get `main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to \`vl_get_printf_func'`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: So now you just need to link in the correct library.  Where did you put your VLFeat installation and what architecture are you targeting?